# Magento2 - Create block on product page before tabs & details but after product media and product info via xml

Tags: magento2, product

I have created a phtml file which I want to add to my product pages.

I know that there are two containers at the top which are `product.info.media` and `product.info.main`. Then there is `product.info.details`, the area where the tabs are and the description starts (`product.info.description`).

My problem: I can't reference the exact spot where I want to place my block. It is supposed to be displayed just between the two div classes `product media` and `product info detailed`.

I have tried

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.media">
    <container name="product.info.afterprice" after="-" label="Product info afterprice" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-after-price">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product-extra"  template="Magento_Theme::html/added/product-extra.phtml" />
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

**OR**

```
<move element="product.info.afterprice" destination="product.info.details" before="-" />
```

but never shows where I want it to be. How can I reference the main product content area and say after="product.info.media" or before="product.info.details"?

Comment: Did you check with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code to `app/design/frontend/{{vendor}}/{{companyname}}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` file

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" after="product.info.media" name="product-extra" template="Magento_Theme::html/added/product-extra.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

If you will add my solution on your catalog_product_view.xml file then you will not required to move it.

Comment: i diid this but tits going after product tabs

Answer (score 0):

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <container name="product.info.test" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product test" after="product.info.media">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product-extra" template="Magento_Theme::html/added/product-extra.phtml" />
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: That did not change anything and made the block disappear...